# Change items in recyclerview when item click on another

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app where there are 2 `RecyclerView` in one layout. I set one for category and second for text based on category. when i am debug my code that give me recyclerview display null value on this line `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` in adapter see in image

I want to select category item then give the text that contain that category.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private List<TextJson> listtext;
    private List<CategoryJson> horizentallylist;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView , horizantalrcview;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    String textUrl = "http:www.extample.com/texturl.php";
    String categoryUrl ="http:www.extample.com/categoryurl.php";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private JSONArray result;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpin;
    CategoryJson categoryJson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_text);
        horizantalrcview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_cate);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        listtext = new ArrayList<>();
        horizentallylist = new ArrayList<>();
        getData();
        verticalData();
    }

    private void getData() {
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        loading.setCancelable(true);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(textUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.e("text", "resopnce is =>" + response);
                        loading.dismiss();
                        verticalParse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void verticalParse(JSONArray array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            TextJson jsonitem = new TextJson();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = json.getString("txt");
                String txtcate = json.getString("category");
                jsonitem.setText_status(text);
                jsonitem.setCategory(txtcate);
                Log.e("text", "is==>  " + text);
                Log.e("cate", "is==>  " + txtcate);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listtext.add(jsonitem);
        }

        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new VerticalAdapter(listtext, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    private void verticalData() {
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        loading.setCancelable(true);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(categoryUrl,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.e("Response is", "first==>" + response);
                        loading.dismiss();
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            Log.e("NoConnectionError>>", "NoConnectionError....");
                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            Log.e("AuthFailureError>>>", "AuthFailureError...");
                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            Log.e("ServerError>>>>>>>>>", "ServerError.......");
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            Log.e("NetworkError>>>>>>>>>", "NetworkError.......");
                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            Log.e("ParseError>>>>>>>>>", "ParseError.......");
                        } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                            Log.d("TimeoutError>>>>>>>>>", "TimeoutError.......");
                        }
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            CategoryJson model1 = new CategoryJson();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String imgurl = json.getString("cat_img");
                String imgname = json.getString("category");
                Log.e("value in","link=>"+imgurl);
                Log.e("value in","imagename=>"+imgname);
                model1.setImageUrl(imgurl);
                model1.setName(imgname);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            horizentallylist.add(model1);
        }
        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new HorizantalAdapter(horizentallylist, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        horizantalrcview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void selectData() {
        NewModel newModel = new NewModel();
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        loading.setCancelable(true);
        String txtselect =newModel.getItem().toString();
        String select_cate ="http:www.extample.com/filter.php"+selectitem;

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(select_cate ,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.e("text", "resopnce is =>" + response);
                        loading.dismiss();
                        selectParse(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void selectParse(JSONArray array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            TextJson jsonitem = new TextJson();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = json.getString("txt");
                String txtcate = json.getString("category");
                jsonitem.setText_status(text);
                jsonitem.setCategory(txtcate);
                Log.e("text", "is==>  " + text);
                Log.e("cate", "is==>  " + txtcate);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listtext.add(jsonitem);
        }
        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new VerticalAdapter(listtext, this);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**HorizantalAdapter**

```
public class HorizantalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    List<CategoryJson> listmodel;
    NewModel newModel = new NewModel();
    String link;

    public HorizantalAdapter(List<CategoryJson> listmodel, Context context) {
        super();
        this.listmodel = listmodel;
        this.context = context;
        setHasStableIds(false);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.text_horigentally, parent, false);
        HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        CategoryJson imgModel = listmodel.get(position);
        imageLoader =CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(imgModel.getImageUrl(),imageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView,R.drawable.placeholder,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(imgModel.getImageUrl(),imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(imgModel.getName());
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                link = listmodel.get(position).getName();
                newModel.setItem(link);
                Toast.makeText(context, "select item select"  +link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listmodel.size();
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_img);
            imageView.setScaleType(NetworkImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_cate);


             }
        }
     }
```

**VerticalAdapter**

```
    public class VerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VerticalAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    String link;
    List<TextJson> listmodel;
    private Activity parentActivity;
    public VerticalAdapter(List<TextJson> listmodel, Context context) {
        super();
        this.listmodel = listmodel;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.text_virtically, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        TextJson model = listmodel.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(model.getText_status());
        holder.textViewName.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                link = listmodel.get(position).getText_status();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listmodel.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texting_status);
         }
      }

 }
```

**Log**

```
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: is==>  Stinging Jellyfish Come to Jersey, But Beaches Sti
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/cate: is==>  speech
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: is==>  Koala Facts for Kids | Australian Animals
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/cate: is==>  motivational
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: is==>  Antarctic penguins ielts reading passage
08-01 18:28:14.021 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/cate: is==>  dance
08-01 18:28:14.061 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/Cache is: 0_0==>com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache@41812ce8
08-01 18:28:24.861 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: resopnce is =>http://www.example.com/filtered/evideo/json/jsoncategory.php?category=motivational
08-01 18:28:25.331 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: resopnce is =>[{"txt":"Koala Facts for Kids | Australian Animals"}]
08-01 18:28:25.351 11378-11378/com.vm.recyclervirtical E/text: is==>  Koala Facts for Kids | Australian Animals
```

**Image**

[image]

**After debug**

[image: debug app]

Comment: How about instead of a Toast message, you start a network request to get categories and set the appropriate adapter?

Comment: toast message is working ....

Comment: Right. You can keep it, but you want that click method to load the other adapter, yes? What have you tried to achieve that effect?

Comment: yes you are right i want load other adapter on click method and doing this...
http://paste.ofcode.org/pwN5cBnCSQrbTumq7Yzay

Comment: You are allowed to [edit] your question with code changes.

Comment: Please remove all `Log.e`statements from `onResponse` methods. Those aren't errors there. You are actually getting a JSON Response

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad problem, so I can suggest some basic approach, which is to pass the click listener into the constructor of the adapter.

```
public class HorizantalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder> 

    /*** Store a reference ***/
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener; 

    /*** Add that reference ***/
    public HorizantalAdapter(List<CategoryJson> listmodel, Context context, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        super();
        this.listmodel = listmodel;
        this.context = context;
        setHasStableIds(false);

        /*** Set the reference ***/
        this.clickListener = clickListener; 
    }

    .......

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final HorizantalAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        .........

        /*** Use the reference ***/
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener); 
    }
```

Then in the Activity, where you set the horizontal adapter

```
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    .........

    /*** Define the listener ***/
    final View.OnClickListener horizontalClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            link = listmodel.get(position).getName();
            newModel.setItem(link);
            Toast.makeText(context, "select item select"  +link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // TODO: Make Volley request for Categories here...
            // Should be able to set other adapter in onResponse there
        }
    };

    /*** Pass in the listener reference ***/
    adapter = new HorizantalAdapter(horizentallylist, this, horizontalClickListener);
}
```

---

In response to the edit, the messages are coming from these lines

```
Log.e("text", "is==>  " + text);
Log.e("cate", "is==>  " + txtcate);
```

Comment: `adapter = new HorizantalAdapter(horizentallylist, this);`  this link display error in my activity

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that... But yeah... I added a third parameter. Please try to understand what I did before you go copy and pasting places.

Comment: Possibly **this** word raises an error. Try to pass explicit context to adapter.

Comment: @faranjit That shoudn't be the problem. That specific line of code that I updated already used `this`

Comment: I mean he may using that line in an onClick or somewhere else so **this** key can be referenced not a Context. @cricket_007

Comment: @faranjit I understand. Thanks for the comment. I have clarified where that goes. But again, the error for the code in that comment is addressed by my response

Comment: @faranjit  you can suggest if is their any solution becoz i stuck on this issue

Comment: @newdeveloper - your image that you addresses is not in a method that I said to modify. You have to show a logcat, if you want help, not a screeenshot of some debugging process.

Comment: @newdeveloper Sorry, but I can't understand what you are trying to show by that. Looks like you got a JSON parsing exception on one of the `Log.e` lines of code... There isn't enough of the log for me to help. Scroll though it or search for the words "Caused by" to find the reason for the error.

Comment: @cricket_007 i have simple concept first display `2 Recyclerview` in activity then click first `recyclerviewitem` (horizontally)  and update value `second Recyclerview` view its means i want call vertical adapter inside horizontal adapter

Comment: @newdeveloper Right. And my code changes should allow you to do that. The problem with the errors that you are seeing are originating from the `TODO` comment of my answer, which therefore seems to be an error with your code, not necessarily what I've shown. Does that make sense?